# unable to create new container in cosmos db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I created my first cosmos db database. In that database, I created a container name person with pid as the partition key.

Now I want to create a new container in same database with name `order` with "`pid`" as the partition key. But the o button is disabled with no warning or error message. What is the issue ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you by any chance using "Free Azure Cosmos DB" (https://cosmos.azure.com/try/)? That could explain the behavior you are seeing (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#try-azure-cosmos-db-free-limits).

Comment: @GauravMantri: I am using Visual Studio subscription. But most likely `free subscription` is reason behind this issue.

Comment: I would not design your containers this way with the same partition key in two containers. What you are doing here is an anti-pattern in Cosmos. We have LOTS of content that show how to model and partition data in Cosmos, including this EXACT scenario. Before you get to far I strongly encourage you to learn how to model/partition data in Cosmos. https://gist.github.com/markjbrown/114179b3d530abe0eaa25fb9ac54b609

Answer (score 2):

Above comments are not exactly helpful. I had the same issue as you did. I could fix it by:

- go to https://cosmos.azure.com/
- add new container
- Click "add hierarchical partition key
- remove the hierarchical partition key

Now the OK turned blue, and I could create the container. In the Data Explorer on portal.azure.com I could not get create containers.

Answer (score 0):

You must select the existing database at the top ('Purchase' database):

[image]

I don't see the complexity of this, to be honest.

Comment: I updated the question. Even after selecting the DB, ok button remains disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but deleting the entire database fixed this issue for me. It does appear to be related to the free tier.